# Column name with dot spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to take columns from a `DataFrame` and convert it to an `RDD[Vector]`.

The problem is that I have columns with a "dot" in their name as the following dataset :

```
"col0.1","col1.2","col2.3","col3.4"
1,2,3,4
10,12,15,3
1,12,10,5
```

This is what I'm doing :

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").options(Map("header" -> "true", "inferSchema" -> "true")).load("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/donnee/test.txt")
val column=df.columns.map(c=>s"`${c}`")
val rows = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(column).setOutputCol("vs")
  .transform(df)
  .select("vs")
  .rdd
val data =rows.map(_.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector](0))
  .map(org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.fromML)

val mat: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(data)
//// Compute the top 5 singular values and corresponding singular vectors.
val svd: SingularValueDecomposition[RowMatrix, Matrix] = mat.computeSVD(mat.numCols().toInt, computeU = true)
val U: RowMatrix = svd.U  // The U factor is a RowMatrix.
val s: Vector = svd.s  // The singular values are stored in a local dense vector.
val V: Matrix = svd.V  // The V factor is a local dense matrix.

println(V)
```

Please any help to get me consider columns with dot in their names.Thanks

Comment: Did you try changing the column names?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan it worked with columns witout dot, but i need to fix it with dots , any help thnx

Comment: What I would suggest is to save the schema with dots, change the column names and after you finish with new column names change it back with dots. Doesn't that work?

Answer (score 66):

If your problem is the `.(dot)` in the column name, you could use `` `(backticks) `` to enclose the column name.

`` df.select("`col0.1`") ``

Comment: Take care however that drop function behaves well with no backticks. In this case: df.drop("col0.1")

Comment: @devilpreet As well as withColumn does work ok with "dotted" names. Apparently only referencing such a column in expressions needs to be escaped with backticks.

Comment: Note this also works: `df.select("parent_column.\`child.column.with.dots.i.dont.want.expanded\`")`

Comment: @Wassadamo further selection from the dataframe using the same syntax does not work. e.g i have this, notice the complaints about the column name is actually in the suggested list.```
AnalysisException: Column 'USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS.`UDX.EDXF.REACH`.`UDX.EDXF.REACH.LISTDATE`' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS.`UDX.EDXF.REACH`.`UDX.EDXF.REACH.LISTDATE`
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem here is `VectorAssembler` implementation, not the columns per se. You can for example skip the header:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
  .options(Map("inferSchema" -> "true", "comment" -> "\""))
  .load(path)

new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(df.columns)
  .setOutputCol("vs")
  .transform(df)
```

or rename columns before passing to `VectorAssembler`:

```
val renamed =  df.toDF(df.columns.map(_.replace(".", "_")): _*)

new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(renamed.columns)
  .setOutputCol("vs")
  .transform(renamed)
```

Finally the best approach is to provide schema explicitly:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType((0 until 4).map(i => StructField(s"_$i", DoubleType)))

val dfExplicit = spark.read.format("csv")
  .options(Map("header" -> "true"))
  .schema(schema)
  .load(path)

new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(dfExplicit.columns)
  .setOutputCol("vs")
  .transform(dfExplicit)
```

Comment: Subject for a JIRA ?

Comment: @zero323 i appreciate your help , you mean there is no other solution to handle this while keeping the same columns name ? thanks

Comment: None that I am aware off, but I never intensively looked for a one. In general you shouldn't use anything else than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` for the column names to keep reasonable compatibility with other tools (including Parquet). And for `VectorAssembler` it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: I'm not able to rename it either- it is failing even when I try to rename and show.

Comment: the `df.toDF(df.columns.map(_.replace(".", "_")): _*)` does not go deeper to nested columns. i had to use an ugly trick to flatten the df (which also had to patch due to the dot in column names), and then use above to replace the dots after the flatten process.

Answer (score 0):

For Spark SQL

```
spark.sql("select * from reg_data where reg_data.`createdResource.type` = 'Berlin'")
```

Comment: could you add some addtional information, why your post would solve the problem? Please consider to check [answer]

Comment: this is an example for spark SQL