# column names cannot start with a number, pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark

I noticed in pyspark dataframes that if the column starts with a number it doesnt show when i call the show() clause

```
meta.select('7.5sig_UCL').show(1)
```

> An error was encountered: "cannot resolve '`7.5sig_UCL`' given input  columns:

But if I change the name of the same column, it works

```
df.withColumnRenamed('7.5sig_UCL', 'sevensig_UCL')
meta.select('sevensig_UCL').show(1)
```

Output:

```
+------------+
|sevensig_UCL|
+------------+
|   121.44565|
+------------+
```

Is this a limitation for pyspark dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `` `(backticks) `` to enclose the column name:

```py
meta.select('`7.5sig_UCL`').show(1)
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51430335/7592064), I think the problem is with the dot, not digit.