# Read HBase Table via Spark-Scala-Phoenix having peroid(.) in column name

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am reading a HBase table via Phoenix in spark-scala, I am able to read a column without a peroid/dot(.)

But when I try to read a column with dot ex: column name "**first.name**", it throws below error. but I can read data from phoenix shell without issues.

How can I read HBase table in spark via phoenix with column name having "dot" i.e. **first.name, last.name** etc

***Error***:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.phoenix.schema.ColumnFamilyNotFoundException: ERROR 1001 (42I01): Undefined column family. familyName=xyz

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column name with dot spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367019/column-name-with-dot-spark)

Comment: Still it error out as Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "`"first.name"`" among (ROWKEY, first.name. I tried multiple different options, but no luck.

Comment: @AnumNuma Could you add the piece of code that generates that exception in your question?

Comment: mapped a view in phoenix on top of the table "personal_data", working fine in phoenix.

CREATE view "personal_data"
(
rowkey VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY ,
"personal"."first.name" VARCHAR,
"personal"."last.name" VARCHAR
);

val df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").option("table", "\"personal_data\"").option("zkUrl", zkurl).load()

df.select(df("rowkey").as("rowkey"), df("`personal.first.name`").as("firstname")).show(10)
HBase table=personal_data
Phoenix view=personal_data
column family=personal
column name=first.name

Comment: val df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").option("table", "\"personal_data\"").option("zkUrl", zkurl).load()

df.select(df("rowkey").as("rowkey"), df("`personal.first.name`").as("firstname")).show(10)