# Map function over column names with

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

newbie to Scala and Spark here.

I'm passing in a CSV as a dataframe, and I want to convert the fields that match a Regex expression from String to Boolean.

My solution:

```scala
val df_in = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("./data/data.csv") // load csv

val cast_in = df_in.select(
  df_in.columns.map {
    case col if col.matches("Answer\\.[aq](.*)".r.toString()) => // check regex
      functions.col(col).cast(BooleanType)
    case col => functions.col(col)
  }: _*
)
```

However, the problem to this is that I have a `.` in multiple of my column names, such as `Input.html` and hit this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'Input.html' given input columns:

I've read a few [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51430335/8698559) saying that I need to use a backtick to group both sides of the `.` together, but I'm not too sure if that's possible with my approach since I'm using variables.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Something like `functions.col(s"\`$col\`").cast(BooleanType)`? Please provide a reproducible example with test data if this doesn't solve it

Comment: Works! Thanks so much